# Grails Plugin referencing discarded custom Service of same name

Tags: spring, git, grails, jasper-plugin

I have a strange problem which prevents my Grails 3.3.9 app from starting up after deployed to a Tomcat 8.

Until recently, we had our own copy of a JasperService. We have removed this and are now using the [Jasper Plugin](http://plugins.grails.org/?query=jasper&submit=Search). Alas, now we are getting an exception (ff being our app)

```
org.grails.taglib.TagLibraryLookup.registerTagLib(TagLibraryLookup.java:113)
...
org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'ff.documents.JasperService' to required type 'grails.plugins.jasper.JasperService' for property 'jasperService'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'de.berlinale.ff.documents.JasperService' to required type 'grails.plugins.jasper.JasperService' for property 'jasperService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

As we do not have a TagLib injecting the JasperService, I presume that there is somewhere still a memory of / reference to the old service which actually tries to get injected into the JasperTagLib of the Plugin, which I can not edit:

```
class JasperTagLib {
  JasperService jasperService 
  ...
}
```

I am using IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.3 and the problem does not occur locally, but only on deployment as a war to the tomcat. I have searched in path and scope for the string but have not found anything.

I would be glad if someone could hint me in the direction where to look for this phantom.

Comment: is your app monilithic? does it use any modules/plugins of yours? what your  `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy` contains?

Comment: We actually have 3 modules we build separately with one plugin (ff-core) which each module compiles/loads on build. The resources.groovy all contain empty bean closures except for the core in which we load the jasper plugin as stated in the docs.

Comment: then the old service or a class referecing it must still be present in one of those dependencies, maybe as a jar file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found this to possibly have been a Git problem. We branched the master and deployed this without any changes and it started up no prob, so we presume it actually was a corrupt Git repo of our master branch. I guess @injecteer was right that it must have contained a reference.

I'll give my question the git tag. Thanks @injecteer